# Docker - Apache2, getting Nginx error 502 (Bad gateway) after setting up OpenIDC

Tags: apache, docker, apache2, mod-auth-openidc

I have a webApp, for which I create a docker image and then deploy.

Everything works, but now I added a new module for `Apache2`, `OpenIDC` `(auth_openidc_module)`, and finally managed to set it up correctly.

To give you an idea, when I hit the url of my webApp, it will redirect me to our identity server, where you authenticate, and then it will redirect you finally to the webApp.

The issue I'm having now is the following,

Once deployed, my webApp, needs to be configured, and to do this, I access to its admin panel and set everything up.

The problem is, now with the `OpenIDC` module, first I get redirected to the IdentityServer and then to my admin panel login screen, and here, when I put my credentials in, I get a :

```
502 (Bad Gateway)
```

Meanwhile, if instead of going to the admin panel, I write the url of a page of my webapp, it works, so what I think is happening, there must be some issue with the cookies or some settings I'm not aware of.

When I hit the Admin panel login, I have 2 session cookies, one is from OpenIDC, and one is from my webapp.

The cookie size according to Dev Tool, is `101` (41+60), if that matters.

On Docker I see the logs, and the error I get when trying to login to the Admin Panel is:

```
AH00052: child pid 47 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Any ideas? So basically this 502 error comes when I try to do a "login" inside my WebApp, which I was authenticated to access thanks to the OpenIDC module.

If I simply navigate single pages of my webApp, it works, just everything that requires input of credentials doesn't.

Comment: Facing the same problem with openresty/1.15.8.2.

Comment: It wa a buffer size issue of the nginx reverse proxy for me.
https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/tuning-proxy_buffer_size-in-nginx